How to secure a locally deployed nginx proxy manager, which is accessible externally via a static IP address
How can I secure a Nginx Proxy Manager deployed for my Homelab, which is accessible externally via a static IP address and port forwarding configured on the router for ports 80 and 443? I want to configure proxy manager in a way that ensures security and protection against unauthorized access from outside. Could someone share best practices or sample configurations that can be applied to achieve this goal? What steps should I take to secure my nginx proxy manager against potential threats from the network?
